# About Manipulate : How to make this work properly?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x], {x, -4*sigma, 4*sigma}],
    {mu, -10, 10}, {sigma, 0, 10}
]
```

I got the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code to work without error messages, `signa` needs an initial value, for instance:

```
Manipulate[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x], {x, -4*sigma, 
   4*sigma}], {mu, -10, 10}, {{sigma, .5}, 0, 10}]
```

Alternatively, just tolerate the initial error messages, and move the `sigma` slider to obtain the desired results.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that it's stupid mistake. Sigma should be >0.

Comment: Or, if you don't care too much about the error (like if this is going to some other user, who might try any input, including illegal values), using `Quiet[ ]` around the body of Manipulate might be a safer option. You can also set specific errors/wranings to eliminate.